# Where is GMail app on Galaxy Note 3 app list

Tags: gmail, notification-icons

I setup my GMail account as a Google account on my phone. When email comes in I can tap the notification to go to the Gmail app. I can use S Voice to go to the Gmail app. However the Gmail app is not on the home screen. I am not using the "Email" app though. Where is it and why is it hidden?

**EDIT:**
It's in the app folder Google. Shame on you Samsung for not making the difference between folders and apps obvious. Well the folders look like this:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

I'll update the question with the answer in a day.

Comment: From the screenshot, I'd say folders are served on a silver plate (and show a selection of icons from apps contained within them) – so it's obvious once you know it ;)

Comment: Yeah haha. I hate touchwiz sometimes. Might make a hybrid rom in the future which is like cyanogenmod with spen support and stuff :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in the app folder 'Google'. Shame on you Samsung for not making the difference between folders and apps obvious. Well the folders look like this:

[image]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>